# C# console app with DB first Entity Framework and AutoMapper, cannot convert Model to DbModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to get a basic console application working so that I can save user entered data into an existing database using DB First Entity Framework and AutoMapper, but when I try to save my local model back to the database I cannot compile because it cannot convert the local model to the db model.

EF has generated the following class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DbModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class contact
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public contact()
        {
            this.address = new HashSet<address>();
        }

        public System.Guid id { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string mobile_phone { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime created_timestamp { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime modified_time_stamp { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<address> address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then have a local `contact` model:

```
using System;
namespace AppModels
{
    public class contact
    {
        public contact()
        {
            id = new Guid();
            created_timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            modified_time_stamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public Guid id { get; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string mobile_phone { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_timestamp { get; }
        public DateTime modified_time_stamp { get; }

    }
}
```

In my console app I use AutoMapper to create a map between the models, get some user input, and try to save that input into the database:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<DbModels.contact, AppModels.contact>().ReverseMap();
    });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var source = new DbModels.contact();
    var dest = mapper.Map<DbModels.contact, AppModels.contact>(source);

    AppModels.contact ContactDetails = new AppModels.contact();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");
    ContactDetails.full_name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your email:");
    ContactDetails.email = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number:");
    ContactDetails.mobile_phone = Console.ReadLine();

    using (var dbcontext = new myDbContext())
    {
        dbcontext.contact.Add(mapper.Map<DbModels.contact,AppModels.contact>(ContactDetails)); // Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AppModels.contact' to 'DbModels.contact' 
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }



}
```

The `dbcontext.contact.Add(ContactDetails);` line throws an error on compile `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AppModels.contact' to 'DbModels.contact'` I have used almost the same automapper/EF code in a web app and it all worked, it seems like the AutoMapper is not telling EntityFramework that there is a model mapping it can use.

Comment: You need to create and use your mapper in your Main method. The stuff you create in InitialiseAutomapper is gone as soon as that method finishes running. You need to read up on variable context. Variables created within a method context only exist within that context.

Comment: Thanks, I moved everything from `InitializeAutomapper()` to the top of the `main()` but I get the same error, I also tried re-using the `dest` variable instead of creating a new `AppModels.contact` but again its the same error.

Comment: Show that new code.

Comment: Updated op with new code structure

Comment: You are almost there I think....you still have to do the mapping when you are calling your save

Comment: Yep, the problem is: `var source = new DbModels.contact();
    var dest = mapper.Map<DbModels.contact, AppModels.contact>(source);` isn't really doing anything. This is like an example of mapping a blank entity to it's mapped value. You need to be mapping `ContactDetails` either prior to, or as you `Add` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception states "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AppModels.contact' to 'DbModels.contact'".

Your mapping is from DbModel version to AppModel version though.  Not sure what version of AM you are using, but there is a ReverseMap function that you can chain to the end of your map call and have it do both ways.

Here is the commit where it was added to AM.
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/bff6e2aa49af3e7b50f527376da48924efa7d81e

For other's future reference, here is the doc to the ReverseMap method:
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

UPDATE:  I just noticed you are using Map() instead of CreateMap().  AM is a 2 step process...1 to create the map and 1 to do the mapping.  You are only doing the second step in initialize, but missing the first part.  I also updated the example below as I had just copied your code verbatim and added the Reverse call.

Change this line in (Initialize method):

```
var dest = mapper.Map<DbModels.contact, AppModels.contact>(source);
```

To this:

```
var dest = mapper.CreateMap<DbModels.contact, AppModels.contact>(source).ReverseMap();
```

Then change this in your save:

```
using (var dbcontext = new myDbContext())
    {
        dbcontext.contact.Add(ContactDetails); // Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AppModels.contact' to 'DbModels.contact' 
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

To this:

```
using (var dbcontext = new myDbContext())
    {
        dbcontext.contact.Add(AM.Map<Src, Dest>(ContactDetails)); // This is pseudo...you have to have the mapper in scope as was pointed out in the comments of your ? and I don't think the Src type is required in most versions of AM.
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here is an example of it's usage:

```
var dest = mapper.CreateMap<DbModels.contact, AppModels.contact>(source).ReverseMap();
```

Comment: I added AM through NuGet (v8.0.0) I tried changing the line to `var dest = mapper.CreateMap(source).ReverseMap();` but get a 'no definition for CreateMap' I thought I was following the 2 steps with the `IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();` line.

Comment: I had to swap the source and dest in the `Add` and now it works: `dbcontext.contact.Add(mapper.Map<AppModels.contact, DbModels.contact>(ContactDetails));`

Comment: Ah true....sorry was working on this off the top of my head while I was waiting on my builds...glad you got it working.  :)